# Mechanize : get all element in element?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

If I get an element `<section>` :

```
client = Mechanize.new
body   = client.get("https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/perdu/")
section = body.search('.dico_definition')
```

and I want get all occurrences of `<div class="dico_title_2">` only content in this `<section>`

I tried :

`section.search('.dico_title_2')` but it gets `<div class="dico_title_2">` of all pages and not only in html content in `<section>`.

`section.at('.dico_title_2')` gets `<div class="dico_title_2">` in `<section>` but only the first occurrence...

How can I get all occurrences?

I find may be the problem :

JavaScript : `document.querySelectorAll('section.dico_definition > *')` returns 7 elements but `data.search('section.dico_definition')` returns 4 elements...

Maybe a problem in interpretation of html?

How can I do in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```rb
client = Mechanize.new
data   = client.get("https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/perdu/")
section = data.search('section//.dico_title_2')
section.first # This is the first element
```

^^^ This will find any tags with `.dico_title_2` class nested within a section tag.

*Note: Variable name `body` could be confused with the <body> tag content, so I'd instead call it something like `html_content` or `data`.*

Comment: I can't use this because I have many sections and I need to keep the order and know the section where come from each .dico_title_2 element...

I need to query from node in particuliar and not all data (thx for rename)

Comment: I edited it to add `section.first` is that what you're looking for? If not, please clarify what you mean here:

> only content in this <section>

Comment: html is like : `<section><.dico_title_2><.dico_title_2></section><section><.dico_title_2><.dico_title_2></section>` I need to do process on each .dico_title_2 but section by section ! like : `sections.each do |section| section.search('.dico_title_2').each [...]`

Comment: @Matrix Not sure I understand - what is wrong with using the code you posted in the last comment?

Comment: `section.search('.dico_title_2').each` will loop on all .dico_title_2 on page, and not only in section...

Comment: I think I find the problem ! JavaScript : `document.querySelectorAll('section.dico_definition > *')` give 7 elements `data.search('section.dico_definition')` give 4 elements... may be a problem in interpretation of html? How can I do in this case ?

Comment: @Matrix you didn't answer what I asked you. In your comment you said `sections.each do |section| section.search('.dico_title_2').each [...]`  <---- why don't you use this? That loops through each section, as you asked.

Comment: no, it's doest works, but I think it's a problem of HTML parsing ;) the website have a bad html code.............